# how can i create a form like this? using html5 and css3

Tags: html, css, forms

The form contains a  border with text at a corner I'm stuck at how to make such such layout.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @tejaswini sana ,,,, Check the Snippet ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<b> <div style='color:darkblue'> A Simple Form </div> </b>
<i> <div> form fundametals </div> </i>

<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Customer Info:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"><br>
  Telephone: <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Pattern: 1-234-567-8910" ><br>
  Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address">
 </fieldset>
 
 
 <fieldset>
  <legend> Book:</legend>
  <input type="text"> Quantity ( Maximum 5) <input type="number" name="quantity" max="5"> <br>

 </fieldset>
 
 <br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
 
</form>
```

Comment: how can we get the rounded edge?

Comment: @tejaswinisana ... used ... <fieldset>   <legend>  Tejaswani   <legend> </fieldset>

Comment: @tejaswinisana ... Yeh Dekh Lo.... For Practical ...  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp

Answer (score 0):

"how can we get the rounded edge?"

By adding style to that element with "border-radius:5px" for example.

Answer (score 0):

**@DanielaB67** ...You want Like This...

```css
fieldset {
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px 10px; 
    background: #dddddd;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<b> <div style='color:darkblue'> A Simple Form </div> </b>
<i> <div> form fundametals </div> </i>

<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Customer Info:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"><br>
  Telephone: <input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Pattern: 1-234-567-8910" ><br>
  Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address">
 </fieldset>
 
 
 <fieldset>
  <legend> Book:</legend>
  <input type="text"> Quantity(Maximum 5)<br> <input type="number" name="quantity" max="5"> <br>

 </fieldset>
 
 <br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
 
</form>
```